# SSRS access fields in a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I want to write a SSRS expression that will allow me to grab the value from Column B base on the max value from ColumnA.

For Example, I have the following values

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test |
| 2 | Tester |
| 3 | Testing |

```
=FIRST(
iif(
Fields!ColumnA.Value= MAX(Fields!ColumnA.Value,"test"),
Fields!ColumnB.Value,0
),"test"
)
```

The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to combine to datasets in one table. Certain fields in the table just needs to select top N values from another dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think that easiest way is to add something like row_number into your sql query (`row_number() over (order by ColumnA desc) rn` and then you can have condition `iif(fields!rn.value = 1, fields!ColumnB.value,0)`